# How to Convert the mentioned Excel format to the mentioned table format

Tags: sql-server-2008, excel, ssis, ssis-2008, vba

I have an excel file as shown below[image]

I need to load these data into a table with below mentioned format

[image]

How to achieve this in SSIS.I mean all the column header would insert as row element as shown below.Is it using pivot ?

Comment: Ok ..let me try then ..sorry

Answer (score 1):

I believe you actually need to `UNPIVOT` the data; it would look like this:

```
Input Column | Destination Column | Pivot Key Value
Period1      | Value              | Period1
Period2      | Value              | Period2
Period3      | Value              | Period3
Period4      | Value              | Period4
```

With the Pivot Key Value Column Name: Period

Comment: @user1254579 Sorry I think I got it the wrong way around it needs ot be Value as the destination and Period as the Pivot Key Value Column Name.

Comment: Yes value is destination column ..But I have multiple periods in the input file,so in this CASE WHICH period has to be taken as pivotkey.

Comment: Pivot Key Value Column Name: Period - Will generate a new column called Period, which will then be populated with Period1, Period2, Period3, Period4 as that is what is in the Pivot Key value.